# Add a column, if it does not already exist column error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got invalid column error
Here is simple code for your reference..

```
create or alter procedure proc_testing 
as
begin

drop table testing
create table testing ([name] varchar(50))

insert into testing values ('testing')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE upper(TABLE_NAME) = 'testing'
        AND upper(COLUMN_NAME) = 'age')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD age int 
END

update testing set age=1

End
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD age int  - are you sure?

Comment: Never store age. People become older every year, and you data will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead. (You can also have a _computed column_ for age.)

Comment: 1. it makes no sense do upper(TABLE_NAME) and upper(COLUMN_NAME) then check them lower case string.   2. you need to check that the TABLE_SCHEMA is the  same as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or alter procedure proc_testing 
as
begin

drop table if exists testing
create table testing ([name] varchar(50))

insert into testing values ('testing')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE upper(TABLE_NAME) = 'testing'
       AND upper(COLUMN_NAME) = 'age')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testing] ADD age int 
END

EXEC('
update testing set age=1
')

End
```